# How do I install/update rasterio offline when the installation procedure given is to install with pip3?

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa, synaptic

https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/installation.rst

I installed the rasterio using these commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ pip3 install rasterio
```

When I type `rasterio.__version__` I get `1.0.8` which is latest.

But the synaptic package manager shows: 0.36.0 as the latest version
[image: Synaptic Version] and in the repository website: [Ubuntugis-stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) [image] also shows `0.36.0-`~xenial0` as the version: [image: direct installation through synaptic]

I have a system which does not have access to internet, where I have to install this rasterio's latest version.

Is there any way to install from github directly? or to update my system's repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed with pip3 you should upgrade with pip3. For example:

`pip3 install --upgrade rasterio`

From the [man page:](https://www.mankier.com/1/pip3-install)

```
-U, --upgrade

    Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.
```

Comment: I have mentioned that I have no access to internet in the system where I hve to install or upgrade this pip.